# Cisco ISR - Dropping TCP Segment: - Reason: TCP reassembly queue overflow

Tags: cisco, firewall, tcp, cisco-isr

Cisco ISR is reporting

```
%FW-4-TCP_OoO_SEG: Dropping TCP Segment: seq:1979009128 1500 bytes is out-of-order; expected seq:1978984512. Reason: TCP reassembly queue overflow - session
```

I have adjusted config up to these limits to no avail:

```
ip inspect tcp reassembly memory limit 4096 
ip inspect tcp reassembly queue length 1024
```

This is occurring on traffic originating from the Internet or from a GRE tunnel, resulting in application timeout and rather slow download speeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can adjust for this. I had to do this on a router:

```
ip inspect tcp reassembly queue length <length>
ip inspect tcp reassembly timeout <timeout>
ip inspect tcp reassembly memory limit <limit>
```

You don't seem to have adjusted the timeout.

Comment: I had to raise the timeout to 40 seconds to stop this condition. Does that seem reasonable? Or is it an indicator of some larger problem.

Comment: You could be receiving a large number of out of order packets. This could be caused by any number of things, but will be a common problem with load balancing done incorrectly. I think 40 seconds isn't too bad.